Gauge charge of the spin connection
When dealing with quantum field theory in curved spacetime, a spin connection field is introduced as a result of the Lorentz symmetry. I'm wondering what would be intuitively considered as "charge" in this case? For other gauge symmetries one has a corresponding charge (like color for $SU(3)$ in QCD,...). So, is it conceivable to also think about some "charge" in the case of Lorentz gauge symmetry?

The charge for the fermion is of course spin, as the name of "spin connection" clearly indicates. "Spin connection" connects different spin states of fermion.


The spin connection is not really an object unique to quantum field theory, it's perfectly possible to phrase classical GR in terms of it. It - together with the vielbein - is merely a different representation of the information we usually encode in the Christoffel symbols. See this answer of mine for the classical geometric meaning of the spin connection.

The equivalent to "charge", for both the Christoffel symbols or the spin connection, is simply whether something is a scalar, vector, tensor, etc. If you insist on using the language of colors and charges, a scalar field is "uncharged" under the spin connection, the vector transforms in the fundamental representation ("has color" in the color terminology), etc.



Hi @ACuriousMind, I'm still not clear by your response with regard to the gauge charge in this case. So, the Lorentz group has 6 generators which are used to define the spin connection (a spin-1 gauge field). The fermions couple to this spin-1 field. So are there some sort of "Lorentz charges" for fermions?

@physics_2015 I don't know what you mean by "charges". Compare this to QCD and its color "charges": The quarks $\psi^a$ transform in the fundamental representation of SU(3), hence have "color charge", the gluons transform in the adjoint representation of SU(3) and have "color-anticolor charge". My second point explains that the correct analogy for this for the spin connection is the scalar/vector/tensor distinction.

Hi @ACuriousMind, thanks for the clarification. So, would it be conceivable that this spin-1 gauge field interact with photon? I had asked that question and it seems that in theories where spin connection is not an independent field, that's not possible. But what about the theories in which the spin connection is treated as an independent field?
